# C# - confused on lock

Tags: c#, locking

For my network based project I need to lock some codes to prevent simultaneous access.
This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Utility;
using DataBaseConnection;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace SunHavenClasses
{
    public delegate void CtatReceiveDelegate(string message);
    public class ServerHandlerClass
    {
        public event CtatReceiveDelegate OnChatDataReceive;
        private Settings settings;
        private DBCon con;
        private Utility.Network.Server server;
        private Dictionary<string, Socket> UsersOnline;
        private Dictionary<string, int> unAuthenticatedIps;
        private string pass = "logisoftlogicielbarundipankar";
        public ServerHandlerClass(Settings s)
        {
            settings = s;
            con = s.GetConnection();
            server = new Utility.Network.Server(7777);
            server.ClientConnectEventArise += OnUserConnect;//.OnClientConnect(OnUserConnect);
            server.ClientDataReceiveEventArise += OnUsersDataReceive;
            server.ClientDataSendEventArise += OnDataSendToUser;
            server.ClientDisconnectEventArise += OnUserDisconnect;
            server.OnBlockUser += OnUserBlocked;

            UsersOnline = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
            unAuthenticatedIps = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }

        private void OnUserConnect(Utility.Network.ServerEventArguments e)
        {
            Stream data = Utility.Serializing.Serialize(settings);
            data = ZipNEncrypt.Zip(new string[] { "settings" }, new Stream[] { data }, pass);
            server.Send(data, e.ClientSocket);
            //MessageBox.Show(e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " is Connected!!");
        }
        private void OnUsersDataReceive(Utility.Network.ServerEventArguments e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, System.IO.Stream> data = ZipNEncrypt.Unzip(e.Data, pass);
            User user;
            try
            {
                user = (User)Serializing.Deserialize(data["user"]);
                if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(user.GetUserId()))
                {
                    server.BlockIp(e.ClientSocket);
                    return;
                }
                data.Remove("user");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                bool passed = true;
                foreach (string key in data.Keys)
                {
                    if (key.Equals("LoggedIn")) break;
                    string[] str = key.Split('_');
                    if (str[0].Equals("GetData"))
                    {
                        string strr = (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                        if (strr.Contains("Users"))
                        {
                            string ip = e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
                            /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
                            lock (unAuthenticatedIps)
                            {
                                if (!unAuthenticatedIps.ContainsKey(ip))
                                {
                                    unAuthenticatedIps.Add(ip, 1);
                                }
                                else unAuthenticatedIps[ip] += 1;
                                if (unAuthenticatedIps[ip] >= 11) passed = false;
                            }
                            /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
                            break;
                        }
                        else passed = false;//server.AddBlockedIp(ip);
                    }
                    else passed = false;
                }
                if (!passed)
                {
                    server.BlockIp(e.ClientSocket);
                }
            }


            foreach (string key in data.Keys)
            {
                if (key.Equals("LoggedIn"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        User u = (User)Serializing.Deserialize(data["LoggedIn"]);
                        if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(u.GetUserId()))
                        {
                            if (User.ValidateUser(u.GetUserId(), u.GetPassword(), con))
                            {
                                /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
                                lock (UsersOnline)
                                {
                                    UsersOnline.Add(u.GetUserId(), e.ClientSocket);
                                    string ip = e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
                                    Utility.Log.Write("UserLog.log", u.GetUserId() +
                                        " Logged In From Ip " + ip);
                                }
                                /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                server.BlockIp(e.ClientSocket);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Stream tmpStream = Serializing.Serialize("Same User");
                            tmpStream = ZipNEncrypt.Zip(new string[] { key + "ERROR_SameUser" },
                                        new Stream[] { tmpStream }, pass);
                            server.Send(tmpStream, e.ClientSocket);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                    return;
                }
                else if (key.Equals("chat"))
                {
                    string ip = e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
                    string message = ip + " : "+ (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                    OnChatDataReceive(message);
                    return;
                }
                string[] str = key.Split('_');
                Stream dataStream = null;
                object obj = null;
                try
                {
                    if (str[0].StartsWith("Get"))
                    {
                        if (str[0].Equals("GetData"))
                        {
                            string query = (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                            obj = con.GetData(query);
                        }
                        else if (str[0].Equals("GetColumn"))
                        {
                            string query = (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                            string[] tmp = query.Split('%');
                            obj = con.GetColumn(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
                        }
                        else if (str[0].Equals("GetColumnDistrinctValue"))
                        {
                            string query = (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                            string[] tmp = query.Split('%');
                            obj = con.GetColumnDistrinctValue(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (this)
                        {
                            if (str[0].Equals("ExecuteUpdate"))
                            {
                                if (str[1].Equals("Query"))
                                {
                                    Query query = (Query)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                                    obj = con.ExecuteUpdate(query);
                                }
                                else if (str[1].Equals("String"))
                                {
                                    string query = (string)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                                    obj = con.ExecuteUpdate(query);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (str[0].Equals("ExecuteBatchUpdate"))
                            {
                                if (str[1].Equals("Query"))
                                {
                                    Query[] query = (Query[])Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                                    obj = con.ExecuteBatchUpdate(query);
                                }
                                else if (str[1].Equals("String"))
                                {
                                    string[] query = (string[])Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                                    obj = con.ExecuteBatchUpdate(query);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (str[0].Equals("ExecutrInsert"))
                            {
                                Query query = (Query)Serializing.Deserialize(data[key]);
                                obj = con.ExecutrInsert(query);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dataStream = Serializing.Serialize(obj);
                    dataStream = ZipNEncrypt.Zip(new string[] { key },
                                new Stream[] { dataStream }, pass);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    dataStream = Serializing.Serialize(ex.Message);
                    dataStream = ZipNEncrypt.Zip(new string[] { key + "_ERROR" },
                                new Stream[] { dataStream }, pass);
                }
                server.Send(dataStream, e.ClientSocket);
            }
        }
        private void OnDataSendToUser(Utility.Network.ServerEventArguments e)
        {
        }
        private void OnUserDisconnect(Utility.Network.ServerEventArguments e)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Disconnected");
            string ip = e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
            /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
            lock (unAuthenticatedIps)
            {
                if (unAuthenticatedIps.ContainsKey(ip))
                    unAuthenticatedIps.Remove(ip);
            }
            lock (UsersOnline)
            {
                foreach (string key in UsersOnline.Keys)
                    if (UsersOnline[key].Equals(e.ClientSocket))
                    {
                        Utility.Log.Write("UserLog.log", key + " Logged Out From Ip " + ip);
                        UsersOnline.Remove(key);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
        }
        private void OnUserBlocked(Utility.Network.ServerEventArguments e)
        {
            string ip = e.ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
            Utility.Log.Write("UserLog.log", "Blocked For Illegal Access From Ip " + ip);
        }
        public void Send(Stream dataStream)
        {
            foreach (string key in UsersOnline.Keys)
            {
                try
                {
                    server.Send(dataStream, UsersOnline[key]);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
        public void Send(Stream dataStream, Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                server.Send(dataStream, client);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        /*changed*/
        public bool AddUser(string userId, Socket socket)
        {
            if (UsersOnline.ContainsKey(userId)) return false;
            UsersOnline.Add(userId, null);
            return true;
        }
        public void RemoveUser(string userId)
        {
            if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(userId) || UsersOnline[userId] != null) return;
            UsersOnline.Remove(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am not sure that I am using lock correctly.Please Give me some advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure in what way?  What is the problem you are experiencing?  There's got to be a few hundred lines of code in that example, it would help if you could narrow it down to the part you think is buggy or incorrect and explain what's happening with it.

Comment: Also, please, for the love of all that is holy, take out those `catch (Exception) { }` blocks, that kind of code doesn't belong in any production app, least of which one that uses sockets.  You have a `SocketException` for that, and if you're able to handle it then *handle it*, at this point you're not even doing any logging.

Comment: Sorry for that.
Well you can find those code starting and ending with /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/

Comment: Sorry. Sure I will use SocketException.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it correctly *some* of the time.  `unAuthenticatedIps` is being protected correctly, but `UsersOnline` is not.  Let's consider two parallel threads passing through your code:

```
                                             Thread A           Thread B
                                             --------           --------
if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(u.GetUserId())  Statement's true   Statement's true
{
    lock (UsersOnline)                       Get lock           Block
    {
        UsersOnline.Add                      UsersOnline.Add
    }                                        Release Lock
}                                                               Get lock
                                                                UsersOnline.Add
                                                                Release lock
```

Notice that both threads A and B modify the UsersOnline dictionary.  This structure would properly protect that object:

```
if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(u.GetUserId()))
{
    if (User.ValidateUser(u.GetUserId(), u.GetPassword(), con))
    {
        lock (UsersOnline)
        {
            // Note the additional check in case another thread
            // added this already
            if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(u.GetUserId())
            {
                UsersOnline.Add(u.GetUserId(), e.ClientSocket);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        server.BlockIp(e.ClientSocket);
        return;
    }
}
```

As far as the last lock goes (`lock (this)`), I don't yet see why you would need it.  `str` and `obj` are both local variables, so you shouldn't need to worry about them being modified by separate threads.  And, as other have stated, locking `this` is not recommended.

Comment: Just a question. As long as you are not using static objects, why would you need to lock resources?

Comment: @TheRHCP: Static instances aren't the only kind that can be referenced by multiple threads.

Comment: Well there are some data access at the bottom of the codes. Actually all client threads will access same object even a data base access class also.

Comment: But I am sure that you saw that in my locking code, it one time locks the unAuthenticedIps and in another code it is locking 'this'. Is this alright to use multiple locking object?

Comment: You can using separate objects to lock separate resources. This is the best way (it increases performance due reducing thread blocking). But using lock(this) - is not a good idea.
Finally, I disagree that this code is thread safe. See my answer for deltails.

Comment: I didn't see you had additional locks in your code.  I'll be modifying my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you read a lot more than you write? If so, a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` may be more appropriate to reduce blocking (take read when you just want to check for the key, and write to manipulate the data).

By that I mean you could do double-checked locking with a read at first, then if it fails take a write lock, **check again** and add if necessary.

Also - the `lock(this)` is generally frowned upon; having a separate lock object is preferred.

Note that to be effective, **all** access must respect the lock; there are some places where `UsersOnline` is locked, and some places where it is accessed without a lock, for example; those second cases may explode in a gooey mess.

For example:

```
if (!UsersOnline.ContainsKey(u.GetUserId()))
{
    if (User.ValidateUser(u.GetUserId(), u.GetPassword(), con))
    {
        /*CHANGE 1.2.10 00:14*/
        lock (UsersOnline)
        {
            UsersOnline.Add(u.GetUserId(), e.ClientSocket);
```

In the above, if it is possible that two threads are looking at `UsersOnline`, then you've already failed by attempting `ContainsKey` without the lock. If another thread is mutating the state when you do this.... **boom**.

Comment: But I did not block any reading code. I blocked only those code which are writing to data base and my two object unAuthenticedIps and UsersOnline.

Comment: Yes may be this is not good idea. Then what should I do now ?

Comment: @Jayanta - consider there are multiple threads; it doesn't matter that *thread A* is only reading; if *thread B* is writing at the same time, you get corruption. Threading is hard - I can't adequately answer a complex multi-resource multi-threading question here, as it depends on **so many** factors...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you code isn't thread safe at all. In your code you locks only modifying operations (Remove, Add), but also you should lock all access to shared fields. Actually this code not thread safe at all. I think that in this case ReaderWriterLockSlim - would be the best choise.

Second. lock(this) - very bed idea. You should use special objects for this.

Finally, I think your code is messy and hard to understand. Maybe your class solve many different tasks. Maybe you should extract some logic to separate classes (for example create guarded dictionaries as separate classes) or something else.

Sample of using [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx):

```
someSharedResource;
someSharedResourceRWLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
```

Some reading code:

```
try
{
   someSharedResourceRWLock.EnterReadLock();
   //access to someSharedResource for reading
}
finally
{
   someSharedResourceRWLock.ExitReadLock();
}
```

Some writing code:

```
try
{
   someSharedResourceRWLock.EnterWriteLock();
   //access to someSharedResource for modifications
}
finally
{
   someSharedResourceRWLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: You should use lock for every access to UserOnline (or use EnterReadBlock/ExitReadBlock when accessing UserOnline for reading and use EnterWriterBlock/ExitWriterBlock when accessing UserOnline for modifications).

Comment: The same way you threadsafe the unAuthenticatedIPs dictionary -- with a dedicated reader/writer lock or lock object.

Answer (score 0):

The advice given so far has been great, but I have a design suggestion you may want to consider.  Replace this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Socket> UsersOnline;
```

with a [custom Thread Safe Dictionary](http://dotnetcommandos.com/blogs/brianr/archive/2008/09/26/thread-safe-dictionary-in-net.aspx)

```
private ThreadSafeDictionary<string, Socket> UsersOnline
```

If its a fit for your needs, it would be a nice way to separate the business logic from the threading logic.